# Having issues with ports in Xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, web-development-server

I just finished making a site with WordPress. I want to make another site with the multi-site function. I followed some instructions and downloaded Xampp but Xampp keeps showing me errors and I can't seem to find a solution to it.

> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  Problem detected!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by
>   ""C:\Bitnami\WORDPR~1.2-3\apache2\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with
>   PID 4768!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured
>   ports free!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the
>   blocking application
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to
>   listen on a different port
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  Problem detected!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by
>   ""C:\Bitnami\WORDPR~1.2-3\apache2\bin\httpd.exe" -k  runservice" with
>   PID 4768!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured
>   ports free!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the
>   blocking application
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to
>   listen on a different port
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [mysql]   Problem detected!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports
>   free!
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the
>   blocking application
>
> 1:39:21 AM  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to
>   listen on a different port

As you can see, there's quite a few problems and I can't really fix any of them. I uninstalled Skype because, from what I learned, Skype uses port 443 and 80. When I click the netstats option in Xampp, it shows that the both of these ports are used by httpd.exe

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had the same problem few months ago, and I found a solution, its actually pretty simple, just follow the steps:

1. Open Task Manager by searching it in the windows search button.
2. Open the services tab, and scroll down until you find "MySQL90" or "MySQL85"
3. If there are two "MySQL(number)" then you have to disable one of them.

This worked for me, it should work for you, lemme know how it goes!